# Show info window marker

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, gmsmapview

What is the equivalent code for iOS to show the infowindow of marker in Google Maps in iOS

```java
Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(latLng)
                 .title("Title")
                 .snippet("Snippet")
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                 .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

marker.showInfoWindow();
```

like this in android.

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(17.4375194, 78.3808417);
marker.title = @"collabor";
mapView_.delegate = self;

marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
marker.map= mapView_;
marker.snippet=@"snippet";
```

the infowindow will be automatically displayed.
refer google's documentation for more information